# How many 4-digit numbers contains number 42

Tags: combinatorics

> How many 4-digit numbers contains number 42 only once(without leading zero)
>
> For example, 4002 - not Ok, 3425 - Ok

My answer:

- Count of 42xx = 10*10=100
- Count of x42x = 9*10 = 90
- Count of xx42 = 9*10 = 90

4242 - not valid(42 twice)

Result: $100 + 90 + 90 - 1 = 279$

Right answer: 278

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: 4242 = 42xx = xx42.

Comment: Oh.. Exactly! Thanks!

Comment: What does mean "contains" in this context, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As Abstraction indicated in a comment, you corrected for counting $4242$ only once, but you'd counted it twice.